# `ipfs add` on a mounted directory, will the complete data downloaded even it is alreayd cached on ipfs local repo?

Tags: mount, ipfs

If `user` add same file/folder to IPFS (if its already cached) IPFS will not fetch any new block to apfs-repo.

```
$ ipfs repo stat
NumObjects: 2796
RepoSize:   168392957
$ ipfs add -r folder
added QmP41fuJg5BcqVeikmUD1fjQhqZUsyUMMiAorMWmtqGnZY folder
$ ipfs repo stat
NumObjects: 2802
RepoSize:   168502656
$ ipfs add -r folder
added QmP41fuJg5BcqVeikmUD1fjQhqZUsyUMMiAorMWmtqGnZY folder
$ ipfs repo stat
NumObjects: 2802         # Remain constant, no new block is fetch.
RepoSize:   168502656
```

As I understand ipfs goes through all the hash of the chunkes in its local repo, and if it cannot find the related hash, it fetches the related repo.

---

At this stage, I am wondering if I have added a file (for example: 1 GB) to `IPFS` from URL using `curl` or a mounted directory, at first try it has to download complete 1 GB file and add it to `ipfs`.

But when I re-do the same operation again, since the 1 GB file is already cached on `ipfs`, will it still be downloaded as complete 1 GB file in order for `ipfs` to check its hashes of the chunks?

```
$ sshfs user@<IP>:/home/user/directory ~/mountedDriectory
$ ipfs add ~/mountedDriectory
$ umount -f ~/mountedDriectory
$ sshfs user@<IP>:/home/user/directory ~/mountedDriectory
$ ipfs add ~/mountedDriectory   # To do this should all files on mounted directory downloaded?
```